# CircleImageView + Layout Inflator Scale type exception?

Tags: java, android, imageview

So I'm using  CircleImageView by ***Henning Dodenhof*** . When I go to inflate a view that contains this `CircleImageView`:

```
 View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_containing_circle_view, parent, false);
```

It's throwing an error, which I traced in the source to:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_XY not
>   supported.
>                                                                   at circle_image_view.CircleImageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.java:122)

```
  @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }
```

Can this view not be used with an inflator and if so, how do I work around this issue to inflate a list item containing a `CircleImageView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of `CircleImageView` does not allow you to use `FIT_XY` `ScaleType`.

Set `android:scaleType` of `CircleImageView` in your XML to a different value if you're inflating the View.

You must have had      `android:scaleType="fitXY"` like this:

```
<some.package.CircleImageView

    ...
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    ...


    />
```

Comment: oh sh*t I just noticed I had set scaleType in there

Comment: I added it to your answer, thanks I completely missed it when replacing imageviews with circleimageview

Comment: Nps, glad if it helped you ;)

Comment: Ya thx bro sometimes you overthink things, I was ready to rip apart the whole Class LOL. BTW this will get you over 1000 gratz